# How can I show the cross of two plots and the corresponding value on the x-axe?

Tags: plotting

Suppose I want to plot this

```
Plot[{x^2, Exp[-x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

what code reaches me to the following image? I mean a plot where cross point has been determined by a vertical line on the x-axe and the corresponding value.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear[plot, pt, x0];
plot = Plot[{x^2, Exp[-x]}, {x, 0, 1}];
pt = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plot]
Show[plot, 
 Graphics[
  x0 = pt[[1, 1]]; {Point[pt], Dashed, Red, Line[{pt[[1]], {x0, 0}}], 
   Text[DecimalForm[x0, 1], {x0, 0}, {0, 2}]}], PlotRangePadding -> .1]
```

> `{{0.703429, 0.494909}}`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The exact value of `x` at the intersection is

```
sol = Solve[x^2 == Exp[-x], x, Reals]

(* {{x -> 2 ProductLog[1/2]}} *)
```

or approximately,

```
sol[[1]] // N

(* {x -> 0.703467} *)
```

The point of intersection is

```
pt = {x, x^2} /. sol[[1]];

Plot[{x^2, Exp[-x]}, {x, 0, 1},
 Epilog -> {
   Red,
   AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[pt],
   Dashed, Line[{pt, {x, 0} /. sol[[1]]}]}]
```

[image]